# Android task/intent: How to implement simple list / display properly in Back Stack

Tags: android, android-activity

My questions are regarding Tasks and the Back Stack and not other aspects of the implementation.

I have a simple application with two activities.

Activity 1: Display list of items.  Click on item starts activity 2 for specified item

Activity 2: Download PDF for item and then display using ACTION_VIEW (application/pdf) intent

Any launch of the application should re-use the existing list activity (or create a new one).  I don't want multiple lists (that is, only one Tasks). ***(Is launchMode = singleTask on activity and implement onNewIntent() the right approach for this?)***

Also, any click on detail should start the detail page which will only show a "downloading" status, once the downloading is done, the PDF viewer is launched and the detail activity is "finished".  The back button from PDF should go back to the list.  ***(If I finish() the detail activity when I start the PDF viewer activity, will the detail activity just drop out of the back stack cleanly?)***

The status bar notifications should re-launch the existing. ***(Should my intent be the same as the main applicaton launch just with Extra data for the details of the new data?)***

The net result is that the Back Stack should only have 4 states, one being intermediate:, and the application should only ever be associated with one Task:

(activity 1)

(activity 1) => (activity 2 - downloading)

(activity 1) => (activity 2 - launching viewer) => (PDF viewer)  ***intermediate***

(activity 1) => (PDF Viewer)

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay!  I got a tumbleweed award for this :)

To answer my own question, my approach seems to be working fine.  Good job, Mike!